# Create account with IDP when Firebase Auth self-service account creation is disabled

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

There are settings to disable user self-service (client-side) creation and deletion of accounts.

[image: Firebase Auth self-service settings]

However, when client-side account creation is disabled, there becomes no way to create accounts with IDP credentials. The admin SDK has the `createUser()` API which can be used to create accounts when self-service is disabled, but it only supports email+password credentials.

Our motivation for disabling self-service account creation is to prevent automatic new account creation if people sign in with an IDP that has a different email address from their existing account. We can display an onboarding flow instead of people unintentionally creating new accounts all the time (it's actually a big problem for us ‍♂️).

Out of interest, I did try the `https://identitytoolkit.googleapis.com/v1/accounts:signInWithIdp` endpoint using service-account authentication instead of a client side API key. While this seems to be undocumented, the endpoint does successfully authenticate with a service account access token in the `Authorization` header and without the `?key=[API_KEY]` parameter but unfortunately it still disallows account creation even when authenticated with admin credentials (error: `ADMIN_ONLY_OPERATION`).

How can we support IDP accounts while disabling self-service account creation?